Generalising power mean to negative numbers
I've been researching generalisations of the arithmetic mean and have come across the definition of a power mean (or generalised mean),
$$
M_p(x) = \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^p\right)^{1/p}.
$$
I've also come across the definition of the quasi-arithmetic mean (or generalised f-mean),
$$
M_f(x) = f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)\right),
$$
and I understand how this corresponds to the power mean in the case $f(x) = x^p$. The latter function requires $f$ to be invertible on its domain. For the power mean to work for all $p$ then requires to restrict to positive $x$ values only; indeed, the definition of power mean usually states that it's only over positive reals.
However, we routinely evaluate arithmetic means ($p=1$) with negative numbers. We can also just go ahead and evaluate the power mean formula with negative numbers for any $p$. For example, for $x = (+1, +2, -3)$ we get:
$$
M_2(x) \approx 2.13,\\
M_3(x) \approx 0.91 + 1.57i.
$$
These results don't match up (at least to me) with the idea of a mean as an "average". For the above results, I would expect these numbers to be negative reals, since the powers should "weight" the -3 as more important.
So I wondered if there was a definition of a power mean which extends to the negative numbers and which gave more intuitive results as an "average" for various $p$.
My guess was a generalised f-mean with
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^p & \text{for } x \ge 0,\\
-|x|^p & \text{for } x < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
That would give
$$
M_2(x) = f^{-1}\left( \frac{1^2+2^2-3^2}{3} \right) = -\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{1/2} \approx -1.55,\\
M_3(x) = f^{-1}\left( \frac{1^3+2^3-3^3}{3} \right) = -6^{1/3} \approx -1.82,
$$
which both match onto my intuition.
Is the above guess a good way to extend the power mean to negative numbers in an intuitive way? Or is there another definition(s) which fits?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-arithmetic_mean

Bonus marks: What is the limit of the guess as $p\rightarrow 0$?

Also interesting as $p \to \infty$

The usual definition of $M_2$ surprised you because $x^2$ isn't increasing. The usual definition of $M_3$ is nicer provided you define $(-x)^{1/3}$ for $x>0$ as $-x^{1/3}$ instead of $e^{i\pi/3}x^{1/3}$.

@J.G. I think that for odd $p$ the standard power mean picking out the negative real root give back the same answer as my "guess".

@Henry The limits are all interesting, from what I can tell... (1) $M_\infty$ picks out the positive or negative number with the largest absolute value; (2) $M_{-\infty}$ picks out the positive or negative number with the smallest absolute value; (3) $M_0$ is equal to zero if there are positive and negative numbers in x, otherwise it gives back $\pm$ the geometric mean. There are some cases with zeros or equal minimum/maximum left to consider.
